# Reguar Expression, UK Post Code, Slight Amendment?

Tags: regex

I use the regular expression:

```
^(GIR 0AA)|(((A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRSTX]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTY]?|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)[1-9]?[0-9]|((E|N|NW|SE|SW|W)1|EC[1-4]|WC[12])[A-HJKMNPR-Y]|(SW|W)([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|EC[1-9][0-9]) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$
```

to correctly validate a uk post code which can generally (there are exceptions) be any one of the following formats:

A9 9AA

A99 9AA

AA9 9AA

AA99 9AA

A9A 9AA

AA9A 9AA

I want to change my expression so that it will allow either a correct whole post code (as it does now) or a correct "first part" of the post code only.. so using one of the above examples:

AA9 would be a valid format

AA9 9AA would be a valid format

AA would be invalid

AA9 9 would be invalid

Thanks in avance,

Jim

Comment: One comment: `^a|b|c$` means `starts with a` OR `has b``OR `ends with c`. Your regex is probably wrong, you probably meant `^(a|b|c)$`.

Comment: @Kobi ... yet the expression correctly matches a post code of CA16 4RR??

Comment: Exactly. But `^(GIR 0AA)|...|$` allows partial matching, it will also *validate* `GIR 0AA:-)Extra Text here` - the alternation operator `|` comes between `^` and `$`. (*matching* refers to capturing text from a block of text, which isn't the scenario here)

Comment: Thanks Kobi - I see what you mean now.
^((GIR 0AA)|(((A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRSTX]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTY]?|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)[1-9]?[0-9]|((E|N|NW|SE|SW|W)1|EC[1-4]|WC[12])[A-HJKMNPR-Y]|(SW|W)([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|EC[1-9][0-9])( [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})?))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are many more optimizations available, but this depends on the complexity of the code...

This is a slight modification of yours:

```
^(GIR 0AA)|(((A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRSTX]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTY]?|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)[1-9]?[0-9]|((E|N|NW|SE|SW|W)1|EC[1-4]|WC[12])[A-HJKMNPR-Y]|(SW|W)([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|EC[1-9][0-9])( [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})?)$
```

As you can see, the ? makes the last part optional

```
 [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$
( [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})?)$
```

Modifying aadravid's simpler version (If you want a less strict one)

```
'/\\A\\b[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]?( [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})?\\b\\z/i'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this from the cakephp framework and works for me...

```
'/\\A\\b[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}\\b\\z/i'
```

Comment: I've put your expression into http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx and cannot get any results to come through?